# Saving a Pdf/Docx with Aspose failed because of java 17 missing fonts in linux

Tags: java, linux, dockerfile, aspose, aspose.pdf

I convert pdf file to docx on windows with **JDK17** and Aspose without any problem.
But when I run the same code on Linux I get this error when trying to save a PDF file as Docx using the **AsposePDF/AsposeWords 23.5**:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.InternalError
java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
...
… 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.(Unknown Source)
… 43 more
```

I already tried to run this command in dockerfile as suggested:

**rpm install fontconfig**

(where does this rpm install these files? seems like the JDK does not contain the fonts anyway)

I also tried to find fonts or **fontconfig** file on the Linux machine under */usr/lib/jdk* and other paths but got no results.

How to handle this issue?

Comment: I found that you have to install the complete jdk package in Linux to have working access to fonts. Just the jre or the headless package aren't enough.

Comment: Have you tried installing msttcorefonts package as well? These fonts should be placed in “/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts” directory as Aspose.PDF scans this directory while generating PDFs. In case you still notice any issues, please create a post in Aspose.PDF support forum which is the recommended and the right place to post such issues so that you can track their progress appropriately. This is Asad Ali and I am  Developer Evangelist at Aspose.